# MVC Email address Validation

Tags: validation, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on validating Email address. Have used the data annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This allows me to have a email address with special characters like Alt+135.

Is there a way to validate the email address so that it contains ascii ranges say, 60 to 125?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RegularExpression` data annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Chris Pratt. There are too many formats. Do you recommend any thing for this ascii range?

Comment: It's just a standard regex range. You just need to determine what you want your start and end characters to be. For example, `[ -~]` matches 64-126 in ASCII, which is basically all printable characters, because the space is `64` and the tilde is `126`. Or, if you need to include something outside of the printable range (which doesn't really make sense with something like an email address), you can use `\x{FFFF}` to represent the character, where `{FFFF}` is the hex value.